# Hacer un insert dependiendo de lo que se escogió en un Combobox

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css, visual-studio

Buenas como les va? Espero estén bien, tengo un pequeño problema, lo que pasa es que tengo un formulario en donde registro 3 tipos de Personas:
1- Funcionario
2- Proveedor
3- Cliente
Mi entidad persona tengo relacionada a esas 3 entidades, Ej:
Si quiero agregar a un funcionario, quiero que me guarde el id_persona dentro de funcionario si es que el combo seleccionado es Funcionario, ese funcionario en su entidad tendrá id_funcionario e id_persona, para poder saber a que funcionario pertenece esa persona, lo mismo para los otros datos, proveedor y cliente, quiero que me guarde id_proveedor e id_cliente siempre y cuando lo seleccionado en el combo sea Proveedor o Cliente para que pueda guardar en sus respectivas entidades, gracias de antemano y saludos !

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "../../config/database.php";
if (empty($_SESSION['nick_usu']) && empty($_SESSION['clave_usu'])) {
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php?alert=alert=3'>";

    } else {
    if ($_GET['act'] == 'insert') {
      if (isset($_POST['Guardar'])) {
        $codigo = $_POST['id_persona'];
        $tipo_persona = $_POST['tipo_persona'];
        $cedula = $_POST['ruc_persona'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nomb_r_social_personas'];
        if (!empty($_POST['apellido_persona'])) {
            $apellido = $_POST['apellido_persona'];
       } else {
            $apellido = "--ES UN PROVEEDOR--";   
      }
        $telefono = $_POST['tel_persona'];
        $direccion = $_POST['per_direcc'];
        $sucursal = $_POST['id_sucursal'];
        $estado = "ACTIVO";


        //validar el campo cedula
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM personas WHERE ruc_persona = '$cedula'";
        //try{ 
        $resul = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $cant = mysqli_num_rows($resul);
        if ($cant >= 1) {
            //header("Location: index.php?alert=8");
            header("Location: ../../main.php?module=personas&alert=8");
        } elseif ($cant == 0) {

            //insertar datos
            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO personas (id_persona, ruc_persona, 
                            nomb_r_social_personas, apellido_persona, 
                            tel_persona, direc_persona, tipo_persona, 
                            id_sucursal, estado_persona)
                        VALUES ($codigo, $cedula, '$nombre' , '$apellido', $telefono, 
                             '$direccion','$tipo_persona', $sucursal, '$estado')") or 
                              die('Error' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
            if ($query) {
                header("Location: ../../main.php?module=personas&alert=1");
            } else {
                header("Location: ../../main.php?module=personas&alert=4");
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Aquí una imágen para que tengan idea!]

Comment: no queda claro cual es el problema/pregunta... lee [ask]

Comment: Si mal no entiendo, tienes tres tablas y quieres registrar en una tabla diferente de acuerdo a la selección del combo box. Es eso lo que buscas o hay tablas intermedias?. Está un poco confusa la información. Ayudaría mucho que nos muestres la estructura de tus tablas.